# .active class not active on Bootstrap progress bar in Modal

Tags: c#, .net, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Modal on my View which contains a progress bar.  The problem is, although I added the active class to the progress bar to animate, when I Inspect Element in Chrome, I can see that the .active class is not applied.

Here is my modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="pleaseWaitDialog" role="dialog"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Processing...</h4>
                <p>This may take a while, depending on your connection.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
                         aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
                        Importing Patients
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a image of the modal when I Inspect Element.
[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you adding .active class before fadeIn the model?

Comment: @liaqatali The modal with the progress bar is typed, with the active class in my view.  On a certain event, I call a Javascript function to open the modal. Here is the Javascript function:  function ShowProgress() {
    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal('show')
}

Comment: OK, I got. And when it opens, the 'active' class disappears?

Comment: @liaqatali That is correct yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your active class by yourself before the 'Show' model line as

```
$(".progress-bar").addClass('Active');
$("PleaseWaitDialog").model('show');
```

There is some piece of code that is removing this class.

Comment: This solved it.  Not sure what is removing the class from the element, but I will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Basically .active class you used is to animate the progress bar dynamically.
This may be occur if some of classes you used over write the .active class. You can test this problem by using this class in nested form or use it one by one.
Otherwise you can handle it by using java-script to handle it dynamically.
Try this :

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not animate the progress bar.